# Advanced Partitions Management in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

My scenario is:
I have 3 Dataflows:

- Recent Data (from SQL Server. Refreshes 8 times a day)
- Historical Data (does not refresh, just once initially)
- Sharepoint Excel file Data

In my Dataset, I want to have a single Fact table that "union all" all 3 sources.

Instead of Append transformation, I want to create 3 custom Partition (well explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CRqdsLjHNA&t=127s).

I want to somehow tell the schedule refresh to only process the Recent Data and Excel Data partitions only.

The reasoning is - if I do Append, then the dataset will each time process the Historical Data again and again.

Now 2 questions:

- How do I tell the scheduled refresh to only process two of 3 partitions? (I can do it manually via XMLA endpoint, but I need it scheduled)
- What if I change something in my report (like visuals) - how do I deploy the changes without needing to recreate the partitions?

Comment: Sorry, but why my question was "downvoted"? Did I do something wrong? If so - what? I am rather new to this community

Comment: mshparber, I just don't get it. I voted to get you back to zero. You're question is great, BTW. This is something I'm used to doing in SSAS, but I'm moving things to PBI only, so I had a similar question -- my partitions being today, current month through yesterday, everything else.

Answer (score 1):

See [Advanced Refresh Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-xmla) which includes [Metadata Only Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-xmla#metadata-only-deployment), and [Automate Premium workspace and dataset tasks with service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-service-principal).

The easiest way to generate the TMSL scripts for the advanced refresh scenarios  is with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16) (SSMS) which has wizards for configuring refresh, and can generate the script for you.  Then you use the script through PowerShell cmdlets or using ADOMD.NET, which in turn can be automated with Azure Automation or an Azure Function.

If you don't need full TMSL scripting capabilities, Power Automate has connectors that hit the Power BI REST APIs, but doesn't support partition-based refresh currently.

But you can call the [REST Refresh API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/asynchronous-refresh) directly through any programming language, or the Power Automate [HTTP Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/web).

Also you should take a look at the new (Preview) [Hybrid Tables](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-public-preview-of-hybrid-tables-in-power-bi-premium/) feature which would enable you to have the recent data in a DirectQuery partition, while the historical data is in Import mode.